# vmware player 2.5.5 no option to create vm

Tags: virtual-machine

I downloaded vmware player 2.5.5 for windows 7 and tried to make a virtual machine.
I do not see an option for that.
Option to open .vmx files is available but what when I have .iso file and need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

2.5.5 is a pretty old version (2010), the latest is 6.0 (2013).  I'm using 5.0 and 6.0 and can verify they do allow creation of VM's

Get 6.0 here:
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0